# Issue while running ASP Dot net core 2.0 - MVC 6 application with angular 4 material

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-2.0, package.json

I have created a ASP.Net Core Web application [like in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmJLz.png) with Angular. After successful creation of application, the solution run fine and output came in browser perfectly.

After, I have included angular material to the above project. Below is package.json

```js
.{
  "name": "WebApplication1",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",

    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

After installing angular material using npm, I have added all *angular/material* module import code in *app.server.module.ts*. Like below:

```js
import {  MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
```

And imported **MatFormFieldModule** into *NgModule*.

And my *html* is like:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Finally the below error is coming in browser:

> "mat-form-field" is unknown element

Please help me to short out this issue.

Comment: I think you might have imported the wrong module?
See here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

Comment: Again I m facing same issue after including                                           import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';  in app.server.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Import below Modules into the app.server.module.ts.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
})
export class serverModule {
}
```

Declare your component Eg. Index.component.ts is declared into your module like below.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  declarations : [
    IndexComponent.ts
  ]
})
export class serverModule {
}
```

Then into your Index.component.html write this.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Note. before all these steps you should [setup angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) into your project .

For any module of angular material that you want to use into your project, you should first import it's Mat...Module into the module that you are working to.
just like above.

Comment: Thank you Arash. Where can I find "SystemJS" file in "ASP.Net Core with angular" project? Plz suggest.

Comment: I am using  "@angular/material": "5.0.2"  version

Comment: I am getting below error:  An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element: 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: I think you are importing MatFormField in the wrong module or you didnt import it at all.

Comment: Generally i suggest you to dont use 'ASP.Net Core with angular'. you better to use ASP.NET Core web application and add an angular project in somewhere else. it's better to have client and server separately in the different places.

Comment: "@Arash" I have tried by importing "MatFormField" in "app.server.module.ts". But doesn't work. I also tried in "app.shared.module.ts". But nothing changed.

Comment: There is no choice, Because its as per the client request, I should develop application in MVC6 and with recent Angular version.